# fopen with UIImagePickerController image returns NULL on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am currently using a c++ library in my IOS application. Its main function is to transmit file via TCP/IP.
Now I am reaching the point that I can send/receive pure String data, but no image from imagePicker can be added. My fopen returns NULL;

```
    hFile = fopen(imageRef.c_str(), "r+");
```

I am wondering whether Apple has restricted the way to get file from iphone?
I　even tried to copy the chosen image file from image Picker to under "Documents" as below:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.image.image = chosenImage;
    // Create paths to output images
    NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/thepic.jpg"];
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    // Create file manager
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // Point to Document directory
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    // Write out the contents of home directory to console
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"thepic.jpg"];
    imageRef = [filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: For some reason the objective C code cannot be formatted correctly.. Basicly, I am getting the image from image picker and write to path under Documents.

Comment: I've just tested and `fopen` works fine on iOS. Try printing `imageRef` just before you try to open it, to verify that it's set properly and that it's the correct file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Which directory did you open the file from? Is it in iphone Simulator folder?

Comment: The Documents directory inside the app sandbox - using pretty much the same as your last few lines of code + `fopen`

Comment: Finally figured it out. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Sharing the solution should help others.